# How to vertically explode a horizontal hierarchy table in MySQL / Databrick SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have a table which has parent child hierarchy as follows:

```
Level0_id | Level1_id | Level2_id | Level3_id | Level4_id | Level5_id
101       |  193      |  192      |  150      |  201      | 300
101       |  193      |  191      |  null     |  null     | null
20        |  14       |  73       |  45       |  null     | null
```

I want to break the horizontal hierarchy and form a vertically hierarchy as follows:

```
Parent | Child | Level
101    |  193  | 1
101    |  192  | 2
101    |  150  | 3
101    |  201  | 4
101    |  300  | 5
193    |  192  | 1
193    |  150  | 2
193    |  201  | 3
193    |  300  | 4
```

and so on..

The number of columns is static and will always be till `Level5`. If a `Level_Id` is set to be `null`, all the following levels will also be `null`, for eg., if `Level3_id` is `null`, then `level4_id` and `level5_id` will also be `null` and so they can be skipped. 
For eg, the exploded rows for Row 2 in the horizontal table would be,

```
Parent | Child | Level
101    | 193   | 1
101    | 191   | 2
193    | 191   | 1
```

How can this be achieved?